# Creating a Button in Kivy

Tags: python, button, kivy

I've worked with Kivy a while back and am leaning on picking it up again. For some reason I am having trouble simply creating a button. The script runs with no errors, but is not producing anything (I get a black Screen). What am I missing?

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MainScreen(Widget):
    pass


class SimpleWidget(Widget):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

**main.kv**

```
<SimpleWidget>
    Button:
        on_press: print('It's working')

<MainScreen>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        SimpleWidget:
            text: 'Train & Model'
            color: 'red'
            background_color: 'grey'
            font_size: 30
        SimpleWidget:
            text: 'Model'
            color: 'blue'
            background_color: 'grey'
            font_size: 30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is, that the .kv-File is not loaded. Kivy says, that, if your kv-File is named "main.kv" and is located in the same directory as your main.py file, it should be loaded automatically. For me, this has never happened, so I like loading the file explicitly.
Note: I also removed the "orientation" parameter of the boxlayout, as it was causing problems:

**main.py:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder

class MainScreen(Widget):
    pass


class SimpleWidget(Widget):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        kv = Builder.load_file("main.kv")
        return MainScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

**main.kv:**

```
<SimpleWidget>
    Button:
        on_press: print("It's working")

<MainScreen>
    BoxLayout:
        SimpleWidget:
            text: 'Train & Model'
            color: 'red'
            background_color: 'grey'
            font_size: 30
        SimpleWidget:
            text: 'Model'
            color: 'blue'
            background_color: 'grey'
            font_size: 30
```

Comment: Yeah that works! you've set the Builder to `kv`, but don't call `kv` anywhere? Also, I had the orientation in there to create two buttons. Seems that the buttons are stacked on top of each other?

Comment: I can't tell you to be honest. It seems to load the file either way. I recently had a small discussion with another user, who claimed, that explicitly loading a kv file is not a good idea, if the file follows the conventions. As mentioned, for me, that never happened, so keep an eye out for any issues. As for the orientation: I looked at your code again and there were some issues with "It's working", as it contained an apostrophe. Deleting the line seemed like the easiest solution to me. Feel free to add it again.

Comment: Yup, I noticed that too and I did fix that. Everything is working, but not to the "T". Only one button is being created and is located at the bottom left side of the App. There is no text on it nor follows the properties that I used above. It does however print out the `It's working` text.